# Sample number with equal probability which is not part of a set

Tags: algorithm, probability

I have a number `n` and a set of numbers `S ∈ [1..n]*` with size `s` (which is substantially smaller than `n`). I want to sample a number `k ∈ [1..n]` with equal probability, but the number is not allowed to be in the set `S`.

I am trying to solve the problem in at worst `O(log n + s)`. I am not sure whether it's possible.

A naive approach is creating an array of numbers from 1 to n excluding all numbers in `S` and then pick one array element. This will run in `O(n)` and is not an option.

Another approach may be just generating random numbers `∈[1..n]` and rejecting them if they are contained in `S`. This has no theoretical bound as any number could be sampled multiple times even if it is in the set. But on average this might be a practical solution if `s` is substantially smaller than `n`.

Comment: Nice question - I agree, I don't think it's going to be possible with that bound (though I'd love to see a solution). The iterative approach is a good middle ground, as you don't need many iterations of picking a random number before the probability of it being in the set becomes vanishingly small (even if `s` isn't much smaller than `n`). Random numbers are quite cheap, as you don't need cryptographically strong ones or anything, and your lookup is `O(1)`, so it should be efficient. You can always have a "fallback" of using the `O(n)` approach if you generate more than say 100 numbers.

Comment: Are you interested in the cost of a single number or the average cost of many?  I.e., what is the cost of generating a data structure than can be reused amortized over?

Comment: @TrentP, he said worst case

Comment: The OP said he wanted a solution better than O(log N + S), not that he was interested in worse case performance.  Clearly, he is not interested solely in worst case performance, or the random Las Vegas algorithm would not be considered, as its worst case is unbounded.

Comment: @TrentP I am interested in the worst case. The random algorithm is only considered if I don't find a better solution, I am not happy with it right now. Unfortunately, I can also not amortize the cost, as I only have do pick one sample per set (but repeat it very often for other sets).

Comment: Sampling with replacement or without replacement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an O(1) solution with O(s) initial setup that works by mapping each non-allowed number > s to an allowed number <= s.

Let `S` be the set of non-allowed values, `S(i)`, where `i = [1 .. s]` and `s = |S|`.

Here's a two part algorithm.  The first part constructs a hash table based only on `S` in `O(s)` time, the second part finds the random value `k ∈ {1..n}, k ∉ S` in `O(1)` time, assuming we can generate a uniform random number in a contiguous range in constant time.  The hash table can be reused for new random values and also for new `n` (assuming `S ⊂ { 1 .. n }` still holds of course).

To construct the hash, `H`.  First set `j = 1`.  Then iterate over `S(i)`, the elements of `S`.  They do not need to be sorted.  If `S(i) > s`, add the key-value pair `(S(i), j)` to the hash table, unless `j ∈ S`, in which case increment `j` until it is not.  Finally, increment `j`.

To find a random value `k`, first generate a uniform random value in the range `s + 1` to `n`, inclusive.  If `k` is a key in `H`, then `k = H(k)`.  I.e., we do at most one hash lookup to insure `k` is not in `S`.

Python code to generate the hash:

```
def substitute(S):
    H = dict()
    j = 1
    for s in S:
        if s > len(S):
            while j in S: j += 1
            H[s] = j
            j += 1
    return H
```

For the actual implementation to be O(s), one might need to convert `S` into something like a `frozenset` to insure the test for membership is O(1) and also move the `len(S)` loop invariant out of the loop.  Assuming the `j in S` test and the insertion into the hash (`H[s] = j`) are constant time, this should have complexity O(s).

The generation of a random value is simply:

```
def myrand(n, s, H):
    k = random.randint(s + 1, n)
    return (H[k] if k in H else k)
```

If one is only interested in a single random value per `S`, then the algorithm can be optimized to improve the common case, while the worst case remains the same.  This still requires `S` be in a hash table that allows for a constant time "element of" test.

```
def rand_not_in(n, S):
    k = random.randint(len(S) + 1, n);
    if k not in S: return k
    j = 1
    for s in S:
        if s > len(S):
            while j in S: j += 1
            if s == k: return j
            j += 1
```

Optimizations are:  Only generate the mapping if the random value is in `S`.  Don't save the mapping to a hash table.  Short-circuit the mapping generation when the random value is found.

Comment: Nice solution. @A1m Here's your answer. It's strictly better than mine if you reuse the set of forbidden numbers.

Answer (score 5):

Say s is sorted. Generate a random number between 1 and n-s, call it k. We've chosen the k'th element of {1,...,n} - s. Now we need to find it.

Use binary search on s to find the count of the elements of s <= k. This takes O(log |s|). Add this to k. In doing so, we may have passed or arrived at additional elements of s. We can adjust for this by incrementing our answer for each such element that we pass, which we find by checking the next larger element of s from the point we found in our binary search.

E.g., n = 100, s = {1,4,5,22}, and our random number is 3. So our approach should return the third element of [2,3,6,7,...,21,23,24,...,100] which is 6. Binary search finds that 1 element is at most 3, so we increment to 4. Now we compare to the next larger element of s which is 4 so increment to 5. Repeating this finds 5 in so we increment to 6. We check s once more, see that 6 isn't in it, so we stop.

E.g., n = 100, s = {1,4,5,22}, and our random number is 4. So our approach should return the fourth element of [2,3,6,7,...,21,23,24,...,100] which is 7. Binary search finds that 2 elements are at most 4, so we increment to 6. Now we compare to the next larger element of s which is 5 so increment to 7. We check s once more, see that the next number is > 7, so we stop.

If we assume that "s is substantially smaller than n" means |s| <= log(n), then we will increment at most log(n) times, and in any case at most s times.

---

If s is not sorted then we can do the following. Create an array of bits of size s. Generate k. Parse s and do two things: 1) count the number of elements < k, call this r. At the same time, set the i'th bit to 1 if k+i is in s (0 indexed so if k is in s then the first bit is set).

Now, increment k a number of times equal to r plus the number of set bits is the array with an index <= the number of times incremented.

E.g., n = 100, s = {1,4,5,22}, and our random number is 4. So our approach should return the fourth element of [2,3,6,7,...,21,23,24,...,100] which is 7. We parse s and 1) note that 1 element is below 4 (r=1), and 2) set our array to [1, 1, 0, 0]. We increment once for r=1 and an additional two times for the two set bits, ending up at 7.

This is O(s) time, O(s) space.

Comment: This is a nice approach (and `O(s)` even without the assumption `|s| <= log(n)`), but the 2nd paragraph could do with some clarification. In particular, it's not immediately obvious that you're iterating over `s` and not `[1..n] - s`, or why we're adding things to `k`. I partially wrote an answer before realising it was actually the same approach as yours - if you make this answer [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) then I'd be happy to flesh out the 2nd bit.

Comment: @hnefatl Edited for clarity. I mention s < log(n) b/c the op makes it clear that O(n) is unacceptable, so this approach is likely inadequate for large s.

Comment: Great algorithm! But is the probability really correct? Considering your example: wouldn't the random number 3, 4 and 5 all result in 6 being sampled. Thus 6 is more likely to be picked than e.g. 7?

Comment: @A1m I had a mistake: < vs <=. Corrected. 4 returns 7, 5 returns 8.

Comment: @A1m. Say we start with 4. There are 2 elements <= 4 so we add 2, crossing 5 which is also in s so add 1 more to get to 7.

Comment: @Dave Did you find a problem in your unsorted solution or why did you remove it? I was trying to understand it right now. s is not sorted in my case. But maybe sorting it, thus going for `O(s log s)` may also be not too bad.

Comment: @A1m It was poorly explained; I updated it with an example, and just removed it while I was editing it so it wouldn't confuse anyone.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the rejection method seems like the practical approach.
Generate a number in `1...n` and check whether it is forbidden; regenerate until the generated number is not forbidden.

The probability of a single rejection is `p = s/n`.
Thus the expected number of random number generations is `1 + p + p^2 + p^3 + ...` [which is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) `1/(1-p)`, which in turn is equal to `n/(n-s)`.

Now, if `s` is much less than `n`, or even more up to `s = n/2`, this expected number is at most `2`.
It would take `s` almost equal to `n` to make it infeasible in practice.

Multiply the expected time by `log s` if you use a tree-set to check whether the number is in the set, or by just `1` (expected value again) if it is a hash-set. So the average time is `O(1)` or `O(log s)` depending on the set implementation. There is also `O(s)` memory for storing the set, but unless the set is given in some special way, implicitly and concisely, I don't see how it can be avoided.

(*Edit*: As per comments, you do this only once for a given set.
If, additionally, we are out of luck, and the set is given as a plain array or list, not some fancier data structure, we get `O(s)` expected time with this approach, which still fits into the `O(log n + s)` requirement.)

If attacks against the unbounded algorithm are a concern (and only if they truly are), the method can include a fall-back algorithm for the cases when a certain fixed number of iterations didn't provide the answer.
Similarly to how [IntroSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) is QuickSort but falls back to HeapSort if the recursion depth gets too high (which is almost certainly a result of an attack resulting in quadratic QuickSort behavior).

Answer (score 2):

1. Find all numbers that are in a forbidden set and less or equal then `n-s`. Call it array A.
2. Find all numbers that are not in a forbidden set and greater then `n-s`. Call it array B. It may be done in O(s) if set is sorted.
3. Note that lengths of A and B are equal, and create mapping `map[A[i]] = B[i]`
4. Generate number `t` up to `n-s`. If there is `map[t]` return it, otherwise return `t`

It will work in `O(s)` insertions to a map + 1 lookup which is either O(s) in average or `O(s log s)`